# JavaScript redirect in if statement that prevents code execution without yielding errors

Tags: javascript

Can I do a JavaScript redirect in an if statement that prevents code execution past that if, without having to throw or generate errors, nor putting the undesired code in an else block?

**Example of desired outcome that yields an error before redirect**

```
if (true) {
  window.location.href = window.location.toString();
  throw "";  // Yields error, but stops execution. return; also yields error.
}
alert("Undesired code has been executed");
```

Comment: Why would you not use an `else`?

Answer (score 1):

how about `setTimeout(function(){throw "sss"},0)` it works in chrome for me

Comment: function start(){if(true){i=0;setTimeout(function(){throw "sss"},0);}alert('hello')}

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `else` block around the rest of the code. I'm guessing there must be some reason you can't do that.

If the code is in a function, of course you can use `return;`

If it's at global scope, I don't think you an stop it except by causing an error.

Comment: It is correct I cannot put an else block around the code following.

Comment: @DavidAndersson: I'm guessing you're injecting into something. Are you sure you can't inject both above and below it? So the bit above ends with `else {` and the bit below ends with `}`? (This would require that you're injecting *within* a single script tag, you can't do that across tags.)

Comment: @TJCrowder: Thanks for the suggestion and having me clarify (which I now have) that putting the undesired code in an else block is not an option.